# Why is Jessie Lite headless but not running SSH by default?

Tags: pi-2, ssh, headless, jessie-lite

I installed Raspbian Jessie Lite (downloaded from the raspberry pi site) to my SD card, plugged it into my Pi 2 and fired it up.
Any attempt to connect via SSH is actively refused. The IP address is correct and the device is showing on my router. 
So I guess SSH is not running by default with that distro.
So I connected my monitor to the Pi but there is no signal. I guess that isn't surprising because Jessie Lite is headless.
So how am I supposed to access my Pi? It seems ridiculous that a headless distro wouldn't have SSH running by default.
Am I missing something?

**UPDATE**
Faulty HDMI cable did not help. Serves me right for buying it in Poundland. Currently installing Raspbian Lite via NOOBS.

**UPDATE 2**
Jessie Lite installed via Noobs (networked) and I can confirm that SSH works out of the box.
I'm leaving this question here as a reminder not to make assumptions. :-)

Comment: I don't believe Jessie Lite is headless it is GUI less.

Comment: So should I be seeing console output on my monitor if it is booting correctly?

Comment: Assuming you are using HDMI and connect the HDMI before booting I believe so - you should get a terminal prompt.

Comment: I also believe that SSH **is** running by default...

Comment: It sounds pretty odd that you cannot see anything on your monitor. How did you verify the IP address then? SSH should be running and your Pi reachable if the network connection is good.

Comment: Yes, you should be seeing output on the monitor.  You'll need to describe in more detail exactly how you came to the conclusion sshd is not running if you expect to be taken seriously.  Right now you have a sort of rhetorical looking question in the sense that it is closer to a statement: "The sky is blue, correct?"  Yes.  In this case it may be closer to "The sky is orange, correct?", and all anyone can really say is no.  I'll be the 3rd or 4th person to add I'm also pretty sure sshd does run by default -- although if the system is not actually running, it would not be either.

Comment: After trying different images (including NOOBS) it seems my Pi is not booting at all. It was working fine this morning on my older Wheezy installation but I am probably wrong to blame Jessie Lite for this problem. Something has gone kaput in the meantime. I'm following all the usual diagnostics for a "no boot pi".

Comment: However, I have seen it posted many times on here that Jessie Lite does not run sshd out of the box, contrary to the documentation. Opinion seems divided 50/50.

Comment: Well, I'll halfway rescind my last comment ;) and say I might have been one of the people to post such an observation in a comment.  Meaning I found it hard to believe it wasn't running by default when I noticed it myself.  But the "no HDMI" output is not right either, and if you have the luxury of a screen (the truly fun examples of this are people that don't...) then you might as well use it and clear that hurdle first.  When a Pi 2 boots correctly, the red PWR led should be on steady, and the green ACT led should flash rapidly and irregularly for at least ~10-15 seconds.

Comment: The green led should then go off, or perhaps flash irregularly but less often.  However, if it never comes on, comes on steady and stays on, or flashes in a steady series of blinks (this is very distinct and obvious and cannot be confused with the "rapid and irregular" normal behavior), then something is wrong.  If nothing is wrong, within 1-2 seconds of powering up you should also be getting stuff on the display.  If not, but the green led looks like it is doing what it should be doing, something is wrong with the connection to the display.

Comment: It's also easy to tell what's up with the boot process (including whether or not sshd ran) by examining the logs on the second partition, although many people do not have a way to access that, which is a PITA.  Life is much easier if you can find a means there.

Answer (score 3):

Raspbian Lite release notes from 25th November 2016:

```
  * SSH disabled by default; can be enabled by creating a file with name "ssh" in boot partition
```

That answers the question I think. :)

Comment: Too many were getting hijacked, the security risk of enabling ssh for a device which always has the same username and password is too big.